# What are my options for a compile-time associative container?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I require a mechanism which given types `T1` and `T2` produces a third type `T3` if the pair (`T1`, `T2`) is valid, otherwise produces a special `Null` type.

I currently define `T1` as a class, within which I can map the valid set of options for `T2` to the appropriate `T3`.

I'm looking for a syntax such that the set of valid `T2` can be defined inline within the definition of `T1`. This is one way to solve the problem, using overload resolution:

```
#include <utility>

struct X {};    
struct Y {};
struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

struct S // T1
{
    X member(A) { return X(); } // T2=A, T3=X
    Y member(B) { return Y(); } // T2=B, T3=Y
};

struct Null
{
};

template<typename T, typename Arg>
decltype(std::declval<T>().member(std::declval<Arg>()))
    call_member(T& t, Arg arg)
{
    return t.member(arg);
}

template<typename T>
Null call_member(T& t,...)
{
    return Null();
}

int main()
{
    S s;
    X x = call_member(s, A()); // calls S::member(A)
    Y y = call_member(s, B()); // calls S::member(B)
    Null null = call_member(s, C());
}
```

The challenge is to handle the case where `T2` is not found - this is handled by `call_member` in the above example. I'm trying to avoid having to define `Null S::member(...)`.

This example uses `decltype`, but is there a way to do this in C++03? I'm open to any alternative implementations (preferably C++03 friendly.)

It would also be possible to implement such a mechanism using explicit specialization, but I'm looking for a method that retains the same syntactic structure as in the example, so that it can be expressed in the following way:

```
#define MEMBER(T2, T3) /* implementation details */

struct S : Base // base-class may contain helper code
{
    MEMBER(A, X)
    MEMBER(B, Y)
};
```

Comment: create map (or multimap) of valid pairs <T1,T2>, then find in map if pair exists, if yes create T3(T1,T2), keep it simple

Comment: @computer It may not be immediately obvious, but I'm looking for a compile-time solution - hence the metaprogramming tag.

Comment: Basically you just want to check if a method exists in the class T2 ?

Comment: As far as C++03 compatibility is concerned, I believe you'd have to know the full function signature you're testing for (ie. including the expected return type, not just the parameters) which defeats your purpose. I'm afraid that in order to have the compiler deduce the return type for you, you need C++11's `decltype` (check for the validity of an expression, rather than for a specific signature).

Comment: @YochaiTimmer The example defines `call_member` such that it returns the type `T3` returned by the overload of `T1::member(T2)`, or `Null` if there is no such member. I'm not interested in the value of the result, just in the type `T3`.

Comment: can we add a macro to say 'this class participates in the type map'?  Ie , in `S`, a `BEGIN_TYPE_MAP` (and an end for symmetry, but the implementation I have in mind makes the end empty).  Or even `HAS_TYPE_MAP`, before any associations.  If so, trusts, sfinae, and in class traits would work.  Wait, do you need inheritance support?

Comment: @syam I have implemented a `HasMember` for this case in C++03, but it doesn't quite solve the problem: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=435ea47b90b395dc091244175b71e8a4-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336

Comment: @Yakk: I only care about finding the valid `T2` within `T1`, specifically disregarding its base classes. I'm trying to avoid extra boilerplate - otherwise I can define `Null T1::member(...)` in every `T1` - but would still be interested in options that add such boilerplate (preferably at the beginning of `S`).

Comment: Have you checked `boost::mpl::map` ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm aware of `boost::mpl::map`, but I haven't tried to use it in anger. I fear it would be overkill for this problem, but perhaps its underlying mechanism can be reused.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Funnily enough, I just discovered that `boost::mpl::map` uses the exact same mechanism internally: http://code.woboq.org/userspace/boost/boost/mpl/map/aux_/at_impl.hpp.html#40

Comment: @willj If you already have boost lying around as a dependency, then I think it's liberating to think of these fundamental utilities as language primitives.

Comment: @enobayram: I'm generating a *lot* of code, using metaprogramming constructs specialised for the task at hand. I fear the additional compile time hit (and additional complexity) that comes with a totally general solution.

Comment: You could use friend functions instead of members.  We could use mine numbers to associate types with integers and size of and arrays to extract them from function calls instead of decltype.

Comment: @Yakk Good point, I had forgotten about the roll-your-own-typeof option. Last time I looked at that it involved a lot of messing around to generate unique integers to associate with each type?

Comment: `_LINE_` was what I was thinking of, as a unique id within the class.

Comment: @Yakk: aha! I wondered what 'mine numbers' were. Yes, I like that - it's a bit naughty but in a good way. I think it could work, but it definitely seems like a lot of work just for the sake of prettying up the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There is the possibility to use a template class inside your `S` structure. Then you can specialize this class according to your needs:

```
struct Null {};

struct S
{
  template<typename> struct map { typedef Null type; };
};

template<> struct S::map<int> { typedef char type; };

template<> struct S::map<char> { typedef int type; };

int main()
{
  std::cout << typeid(S::map<int>::type).name() << std::endl;  // c
  std::cout << typeid(S::map<char>::type).name() << std::endl; // i
  std::cout << typeid(S::map<S>::type).name() << std::endl;    // 4Null
}
```

The syntax for defining it is not exactly as you wanted (you have to declare the specializations outside the class, and I don't think you can factor out the initial `Null` mapping in a base class) but at least it's simple *and* C++03 compatible. A few macros could make it nicer to use, though, something along the lines of:

```
struct S { INITIALIZE_TYPES_MAP; };
ADD_MAPPED_TYPE(S, int, char);
ADD_MAPPED_TYPE(S, char, int);
//...
std::cout << typeid(GET_MAPPED_TYPE(S, int)).name() << std::endl;
```

Those macros are trivial to write so I won't bore you with them.

Comment: Looks good. If only the explicit specializations could be defined inline ;). I am obsessing over mimimal syntax!

Comment: @willj Well partial specializations can be defined within the definition of the surrounding class if that's what you're referring to. [C++03 live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ca9c7f6199d36a0f99d9eff96c3f67b8-7bc6d93f4b35b9d88b63c2a04b6e3cf7)

Comment: @DyP I was under the impression that wasn't possible! It seems a little odd to have the extra `S::` in the member name.

Comment: @willj That's just copy-and-waste from syam's code. It works because of the *injected-class-name*.

Answer (score -1):

Here is half of a solution (map T1 & T2 to T3, but not map to Null then invalid)

```
// Need a typedef for each valid combination
typedef T1_T2 T3;
#define MAP(x,y) x ## _ ## y
```

If you know all invalid combinations ahead of time, you could do

```
typedef T1_T3 Null;
typedef T2_T3 Null;
```